# Cannot play stream from URL (radio)

Tags: android, media-player

I want to stream music that a radio station plays, from my android phone.

```
package com.greenbits.kissfmcyprus;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener
{
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://live.istoikona.com/kiss");
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        Log.e(TAG, "ready to call prepare");
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "prepared successfully");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

I have also declared in the manifest that I want to use the internet.
In the log, I get an error with code -1004, which is **File or network related operation errors.**

When I try to open the same URL in PC's browser, it works, and music is played.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: paste your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

```
    String urlAdress ="http://live.istoikona.com/kiss";   
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlAdress);
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    Log.d("UYARI", "PLAYER WAS CREATED");

    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);

    Log.d("UYARI", "SET DATA SOURCE WAS INITIALIZED");

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!mp.isPlaying()) {

                mp.start();
                Log.d("UYARI", "AT LAST PLAYER WAS STARTED");


            }

        }
    });
    player.prepareAsync();
    Log.d("UYARI", "PREPAREASYNC WAS DONE ");
```

**But dont forget to test these codes in your real phone or smart. because of sometimes emulater couldnt play some url's. In addition to this dont forget internet permission in manifest xml  **